# List Item First Indentation Not Lining Up

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In each list item I have a text box within a div element.

```
<html>   
    <body>       
        <!-- Window -->
        <div id="sample_container_id">
            <div class="bucket" id="defaultBucket">
                <h3>Default Bucket</h3>
                <input type="button" value="Add" class="button">
                <div class="innerBucket">
                    <ul id="tasks">
                        <li>
                            <div class="TaskDiv">
                                <input type="text" class="TaskTextInput">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="TaskDiv">
                                <input type="text" class="TaskTextInput">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="TaskDiv">
                                <input type="text" class="TaskTextInput">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- innerBucket -->
            </div> <!-- defaultBucket -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 15px;
}

h1, p 
{
    color: #333;
}

#sample_container_id 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
}

.innerBucket
{
    width: 290px;
    height: 355px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white; 
}

.bucket
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
}

.bucket h3
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: -10px;
}

.bucket ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    position: relavtive;
    list-style: none;
}

.bucket ul li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.bucket .button
{        
    background-color:#fbb450;       
    border:1px solid #c97e1c;

    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 11px;
    text-decoration:none;

    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #8f7f24;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

As you may notice the first item is indented, and I would like the list items to all be aligned on the left. How do I fix this with the CSS (there probably is a lot of things wrong with my CSS, I was trying everything)?

**EDIT**

I added some more code. You should be able to replicate the problem now.
I didn't want to post a wall of code :)

**Solution**

I found the solution to the problem. The problem was actually the `<h3>` element. The bottom margin was forcing the first element off to the side.

[image]

Adding this fixed the problem:

```
.bucket h3
{
    ...
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please break this [Pen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/wIprz) to show your problem :-)

Comment: Is that a copy and paste? You have the position of the ul set to relavtive. And you don't have to explicitly position everything, honest.

Comment: the code above don't gives the same result as shown on your screenshot

Comment: I've added some more code. You should now be able to replicate the problem. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't float the divs, if you do make sure to clear them or you get
  what FakeRainBrigand got in his pen.
- Spell relative right For that
  matter take the positioning out of that code, it's pointless.
- list items by definition are block elements, you don't need to declare
  that either.
- Close your input tags.

The float is likely the issue, pushing the divs against some invisible element.

```
.TaskDiv
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    list-style: none;
}

ul li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Yw4tB/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll for sure take your advice regarding and fix up the HTML and CSS. The solution ended up being something different. It was my fault for not posting more code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem. The issue was the margin of the header forcing the div over (see the end of my question). The solution was simple once I figured that out.

Simply adding this to the h3 styling fixed my problem:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```